# Browser adds my website url as prefix to all links in my page content

Tags: php

I have a problem which is that in my website all `<a></a>` tags get automatically a `prefix` which is my website address. 
For example: 
My website `home url` is: `mysite.com`
Now when I create a normal `<a></a>` tag in my page like `<a href="check.com"> check </a>` ,
it will be rendered in my page as `<a href="mysite.com/check.com"> check </a>`.

Does anyone know why this is happening??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"My website home url is: `mysite.com`"* -- `mysite.com` is not an [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL). It is just the host name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not caused by Laravel. The browser cannot interpret the target since you haven't indicated that the resource is a URL. As a result it cannot differentiate between external URLs, relative URLs and files.

Add the protocol in order for it to work as you expected:

```
<a href="http://check.com"> check </a>
```

Alternatively you can also add 2 slashes, however that won't work if you save the page output as a HTML on your device and open it from there.

```
<a href="//check.com"> check </a>
```